# How to extract the p MSB bits of a given number

Tags: c++

Ok so I'm implementing a hash function that utilizes the multiplication method.

I have been given a K and a S (where S = A * 2^word). I have found my p and all I need to do is to extract the p most significant bits from the product of KS. 
So let's say KS = 51 which is represented as 110011 in binary and p = 4; I'd need to extract the 4 most significant bits i.e. 1100 or 12 and that would in theory be h(k) for a multiplication hash function!

How may I go about doing so?

A simple

```
int tempHold = k * s;
tempHold << p;
```

is not working.

Comment: `1100` is not equal to `48` !

Comment: fixed, my apologies!

Comment: There are already lots of different hash functions for every purpose out there, modern ones are SHA-3 for general hashing or Argon2 for password hashing. There are a lot of mistakes you can do implementing a homebrew hash function. Or is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @nada apologies on the late reply, it's a homework assignment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the floor of the log base 2 of said number to get the number of bits, N, in the number, then perform a rightshift (>>) by (N -p). This would leave behind the p most significant bits.

Comment: thank you! I was also given a w (8 * sizeof(unsigned)) so I just right shifted the product by (w - p) !!!

Comment: out of curiosity, how does this always work. I'm a bit of a novice at bit manipulation. thanks in advance

Comment: As you know, any number can be expressed as a sequence of bits, with each bit denoting a value of 2^(x-1), where x is the position in the of the bit in the sequence. A rightshift of 1 bit removes the LSB and shifts all higher bits down by 1 place. To get the p most significant bits, you must get rid of the (w-p) least significant bits, thus you perform a rightshift (w-p) times.